# ¿Qué hace el siguiente código de ensamblador?

Tags: masm

Hice el hola mundo en ensamblador y todo bien, pero quisiera saber para que sirve exactamente la siguiente línea.

```
    DB 32 DUP ('stack___')
```

La línea va dentro del segmento de **pila**  **(SEGMENT stack)**.

Comment: si te sirve la respuesta puedes marcarla como resuelta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genera el duplicado 32 veces de ('stack___') para la pila. es como :

```
INPUTSTR DB stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___,stack___
```

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h2ye0a0.aspx)

y loque hace stack: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556714/how-does-the-stack-work-in-assembly-language)